# Oncreate wait for the completion of all methods before show activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-threads

I'm trying to show an intro for my andorid app, the method that initializes this intro is called from the `onCreate()` method of the main activity, doing a debug when i put a break point on the method that shows intro activity, in my device the main activity is displayed.

Are there any way to prevent this ?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    validateFirstTime();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private void validateFirstTime() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  Initialize SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
            boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

            //  If the activity has never started before...
            if (isFirstStart) {

                //  Launch app intro
                final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                //  Make a new preferences editor
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();

                //  Edit preference to make it false because we don't want this to run again
                e.putBoolean("firstStart", true);

                //  Apply changes
                e.apply();
            }
        }
    });
    // Start the thread
     t.start();
}
```

i'm putting the break point in the if statement of validateFirstTime() Method,
before resume the breakpoint the activity is already displayed in te device.

why ?

Answer (score 1):

This because the code inside `validateFirstTime()` is running on different thread than the following code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

which is running on Main thread.

You can fix the problem by moving your code outside of the thread like this:

```
private void validateFirstTime() {
  SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

  //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
  boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

  //  If the activity has never started before...
  if (isFirstStart) {

    //  Launch app intro
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    //  Make a new preferences editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();

    //  Edit preference to make it false because we don't want this to run again
    e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

    //  Apply changes
    e.apply();
  } else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

Then in `onCreate()` you can use this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    validateFirstTime();
}
```

---

Or, you can use a more simpler way by moving all the checking of first time as a method like this:

```
private boolean isFirstTimeUsage() {
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

  //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
  boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

  //  If the activity has never started before...
  if (isFirstStart) {
    //  Make a new preferences editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();

    //  Edit preference to make it false because we don't want this to run again
    e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

    //  Apply changes
    e.apply();
  }

  return isFirstStart;
}
```

Then you can use the method in `onCreate` with something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean isFirstTime = isFirstTimeUsage();
    if(isFirstTime) {
      //  Launch app intro
      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
    } else {
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```